# Can money be refunded after order cancellation in HDFC multicurrency forex card?

Tags: india, foreign-exchange, refund

I ordered something online on Amazon while in US using my HDFC multicurrency forex card. A day later the payment was processed and the amount got deducted from my forex card. I had to cancel the order later on due to some reason. Amazon said they'll refund any deducted amount in 1-2 days but how are they supposed to do that since it is a prepaid card and there is no bank account associated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The refund will be made to the multi-currency card. There is no need for an associated bank account. Consider how did you load currency into your card? In the same way, the refund will happen.

Comment: I don't think the refund will happen in the currency the card was loaded in - I presume the refund will occur in the currency that Amazon received, whether the rate has  gone up or down, and the card itself will show the receipt as its base currency, which may be higher or lower than what was originally loaded in that currency.